# SQL Server - change tracking on Views data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to track changes on views data. I don't think it is possible out of the box with current sql server change tracking. Has anyone come up with a solution to this one?

//edit
I'm synchronizing data between two databases. Synchronization works mostly on views (some tables too), so I need to track changes that are being made on views data (insert/update/delete). The task is not trivial, because some views are just JOINS and others use PIVOT.

Comment: While not an aswer to the question. It seems it shold be possible given that full text indexing seems to use change tracking, and certainly allow indexing a view, as long as it is an indexed view.

Comment: Indexing views is a tricky and nasty thing. Pivot - can't index, left join - can't index. There are many features you can't use if you want to have your view indexed. Look at here: http://sqlheaven.blogspot.com/2011/06/indexed-view-limitations.html

Comment: @kubal5003, have you found any solutions? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, this was a loong time ago. I don't even remember the problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No. No, you cannot. I wish you could.

Comment: Seriously - what is the value of answering a question asked 8 years ago?

Comment: @kubal5003 To improve the knowledge base for those still looking for the best answer 8 years later.

Answer (score -2):

You can track changes with [DDL Triggers.](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-to-capture-schema-changes). Seems like these work on SQL Server version 2005 and above.

One benefit is for users that are just not going to use source control (It happens). This can be a problem if the use GUI view creating and don't want to export to the actual text.

This records the previous versions (you already have the current in the database itself) without any user involvement.

This would free you up from having to be the bottle neck and approve or apply every change.

I didn't read enough of this to see if it would capture the user who submitted the change.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood the idea. There was more info about it in comments below, but I updated my post now too.

Answer (score -4):

Manage the changes in your source control server and generate your views WITH ENCRYPTION so people don't mess with them on the server.

Comment: It's not about changes in the source of the views, but in the data. SQL Server 2008 has built-in change tracking for tables, but nothing like this for views.

Comment: Ah. Updateable views? Why on Earth would you want those? (If you really need them to be updateable, you're stuck doing triggers).

Comment: Updates are being made on underlying tables not on the views themselves, but I'm synchronizing data to another database, so it would be nice if I could just get info about what changed on the view not on the underlying table. Ie. in one view I'm using PIVOT so it's not straightforward..

Comment: There is no way to provide the functionality you want in the platform without trashing performance.

Comment: Performance is not the key thing here. It's intended for small companies with limited amount of users (up to 10), so almost anything will do. Synchronization can even be performed overnight. Hardware is also not a real problem. Besides one should always implement first and then optimize, not the other way round.

Comment: That's not the point. Think of how SQL server would have to implement automatic tracking OF UNDERLYING TABLES in your PIVOT-containing view.

Comment: SQL Server uses snapshots to store information about changes, so computing differences using snapshots is a one time kill to the server - only when someone demands the info.

Comment: SQL supports having indexes on certain classes of views.  It's not unreasonable to think this would be possible, considering SQL needs to be able to track changes enough to update such an index